# Why does wget try to access wrong target?

Tags: backup, wget, https

I am trying to mirror a site which I manage for backup purposes.

Here is my wget command:

```
wget \
 --mirror \ # Download the whole site, updating local files as needed.
 --page-requisites \ # Get all assets/elements (CSS/JS/images).
 --adjust-extension \ # Save files with .html on the end.
 --span-hosts \ # Include necessary assets from offsite as well.
 --convert-links \ # Update links to still work in the static version.
 --backup-converted \ # Backup original HTML files before converting links
 --restrict-file-names=windows \ # Modify filenames to work in Windows as well.
 --domains=********.*** \ # Do not follow links outside this domain.
 --no-parent \ # Don't follow links outside the directory you pass in.
 --append-output=wget.log \ # Send output to log file
 --rejected-log=wget-rejected.log \ # separate log file for rejected requests
 --reject=SwitchToAdmin,SignOut
 --show-progress \ # Show progress bar
 --random-wait \ # Roandomize wait  time (0.5 - 1.5 * wait)
 --wait=2 \ # median wait time in seconds
 https://********.*** # The URL to download
```

and here are the results:

```
--2021-05-03 14:14:20--  http://%20/
Resolving   ( )... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘ ’
--2021-05-03 14:14:20--  http://download/
Resolving download (download)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘download’
--2021-05-03 14:14:20--  http://the/
Resolving the (the)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘the’
--2021-05-03 14:14:20--  http://whole/
Resolving whole (whole)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘whole’
--2021-05-03 14:14:20--  http://site,/
Resolving site, (site,)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘site,’
--2021-05-03 14:14:20--  http://updating/
Resolving updating (updating)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘updating’
--2021-05-03 14:14:20--  http://local/
Resolving local (local)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘local’
--2021-05-03 14:14:20--  http://files/
Resolving files (files)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘files’
--2021-05-03 14:14:20--  http://as/
Resolving as (as)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘as’
--2021-05-03 14:14:20--  http://needed./
Resolving needed. (needed.)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘needed.’
wget.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `('
wget.sh: line 9: `     --page-requisites \ # Get all assets/elements (CSS/JS/images).'
```

Why is wget trying to access http://, when I asked it to access https://?

Comment: You can't have further characters after the line continuation character `\\`

Answer (score 2):

In bash, `\` is used to escape the following character.

It is often used (and probably this is what you want) to **escape the newline character** to enable a multi-line command.

```bsh
wget \
-arg1 \
-arg2
```

If you want the `\` to escape the newline character, it must be placed directly in front of it, otherwise it won't work:

```bsh
wget \ # some comment
-arg1 \
-arg2
```

... will escape the space and the following will be executed (check `set -x`):

```
+ wget ' #' some comment
```

---

Further, as your next line(s) is/are not connected anymore, you will likely get an error saying something like:

```
`-arg1`: command not found.
```

Comment: Indeed, I noticed shortly after posting that I had left out the EOL escape after --reject=SwitchToAdmin,SignOut, but I didn't realize that the comments were not allowed.  In fact, I got this format from another website: many thanks for the explanation!
Had I received an error message like the one you expected, I would have noticed these problems sooner! ;-}

Comment: P.S. I don't see a way to get wget to read these parameters from a file.  Do I simply have to do without the documentation, or is there another way?